Does Allah has more than two hands?
Assalamualaikum is the word يَدَاهُ in Quran 5:64 a dual or plural in the Arabic language someone told me thats its more than two.

Firstly, I would like to address the fact that the hands here are not physical, but used metaphorically. The wider sentence here is يَدَاهُ مَبْسُوطَتَانِ, literally meaning that Allah's 'hands' are stretched out, but implying that Allah gives freely and emphasises his generosity.
In terms of the Arabic itself, يَدَاهُ, consists of two words, the first being the dual form of the word يد (hand) which is يدان, and the second being the pronoun ه, meaning his. The pronoun causes the ن at the end to drop off, giving the word we see, يَدَاهُ.
In summary, the literal Arabic uses a dual form, meaning two hands, but most translations take a metaphorical meaning.

Seeing the salafi tag in the question this answer doesn't seem to reflect their view at all. Since they don't interpret verses about Allah's attributes, but take them literally.

@Medi1Saif , that is correct, but I expressed my own view, as well as giving the literal meaning in the middle paragraph if they wish to take their own interpretation
